# Page object isn't returned with the categories

Tags: typo3

I am developping a plugin to list all the page of a certain type. I added the new type without any difficulties. I also wanted to display the categories of the page but when I debug the objects in the template, I only see the number of categories associated with the page.

The repository doesn't return the categories of the page and I can't find why. Also, as a test, I checked if a normal page would return the childrens but it doesn't even count the number of categories attributed to the page.

I took a look into the `sys_category_record_mm` table and the rows are created correctly. I haven't touched the categories in the TCA.

This is the *items* configuration in the `sys_category` TCA

```
items
    config
        allowed = *
        internal_type = db
        MM = sys_category_record_mm
        MM_oppositeUsage
        pages
            0 = categories
        sys_file_metadata
        tt_content
        tx_news_domain_model_news
            0 = categories
        show_thumbs =
        size = 10
        type = group
    exclude = 0
    label = LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.items
```

This is my page *categories* config in the TCA

```
categories
    config
        autoSizeMax = 50
        foreign_table = sys_category
        foreign_table_where = AND sys_category.sys_language_uid IN (-1, 0) ORDER BY sys_category.sorting ASC
        maxitems = 9999
        MM = sys_category_record_mm
        MM_match_fields
            fieldname = categories
            tablenames = pages
        MM_opposite_field = items
        renderType = selectTree
        size = 10
        treeConfig
            appearance
                expandAll = 1
                maxLevels = 99
                showHeader = 1
            parentField = parent
        type = select
    exclude = 1
    label = LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.categories
```

I didn't add more category selector to the page. Either manually or via the `makeCategorizable` so that should still the default configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using extbase as you are talking about *objects*? If yes, then the *categories* property got a wrong type in your model. Instead of string, use

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category>
 * @lazy
 */
protected $categories;
```

If you are not using extbase, just do an additional query to `sys_category_record_mm` to fetch the according counts.

Comment: My plugin use extbase, yes. But since I use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository, I now realize that it doesn't extends anything from extbase. I'll have to do it manually I guess. Thank you.